# No internet connection, Win7, DNS DOES resolve

Tags: windows-7, dns, home-networking

I just installed a fresh new copy of Win 7 64-bit. My ipconfig says that my dns do resolve, and everything looks as it should. Device Manager tells me that my network drivers are fine, and working as they should. If I use cmd to ping sites online it will time out. I'm using wired connection, and my motherboard is Asus P5Q PRO.

Here is a pic of my ipconfig: 
[image]

If I try to ping a web-domain, it will succeed with converting the domain to an IP address, but my packages wont be answered: 
[image]

I've updated the drivers to the newest version available, but it doesn't make a difference.